# How to get the output of top command consistently as a stream?

Tags: linux, command-line

I want to do a little experiment that converts the output of `top` to a json file over http and then feeds it to a data visualization tool like D3.js.

I could do something like:

```
top | awk '/Mem/ {print "cpu used: " $2}'
```

and get:

```
cpu used: 22M
```

but I have to execute the  above command repeatedly to get a data over time.

Is there a way to run top without stopping it, and get a stream of data instead of repeatedly executing it?

Comment: Have a look at `/proc/loadavg`, `/proc/meminfo`.  The system already collects these stats in easy to consume files.

Comment: `man 5 proc` for file formats.  http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc